# SQLite delete not works

Tags: sqlite

I' ve a SQLite table called WPList with 4 column

`ID (int), ID_quote (int foreign key), ID_workperformance (int foreign key), expire_date (text)`

I' ve a big problem when I try to eliminate a row with this query:

`DELETE FROM WPList WHERE ID_workperformance = 12 & ID_quote = 21`

I' m absolutely sure that ID_workperformance 12 and ID_quote 21 exist in table but when I execute this query nothing happen. Can you help me please? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

It's `AND`, not `&`.

```
DELETE FROM WPList WHERE ID_workperformance = 12 AND ID_quote = 21
```

it seems `&` is equivalent but a little harder to use, as in you need to add brackets in your case

```
DELETE FROM WPList WHERE ((ID_workperformance = 12) & (ID_quote = 21))
```

Without the backet, the execution plan (see [EXPLAIN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html)) of your syntax is the same as

```
DELETE FROM WPList WHERE (ID_workperformance = 12 & ID_quote) = 21
```

which explains why it does not work as expected.

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel, well put.  :-)